# Comparing two GUIDs for equality in C++

Tags: visual-c++, guid, equality

I am looking for the easiest way to compare two GUIDs for equality in C++. Surely there is a predefined function for that.

The solution needs to work with [Visual C++ 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions).

I am talking of GUID as defined in Guiddef.h:

```
typedef struct _GUID {
    unsigned long  Data1;
    unsigned short Data2;
    unsigned short Data3;
    unsigned char  Data4[ 8 ];
} GUID;
```

Comment: Have you looked at [boost?](http://www.boost.org/libs/uuid)

Comment: Related: [How to compare two GUID?](http://www.progtown.com/topic1087358-how-to-compare-two-guid.html)
 — I posted my anser there as ***srgloureiro***

Comment: Referenced in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347872/is-it-ok-to-make-a-qa-of-a-thing-that-ive-already-answered-elsewhere) (in a comment and an answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you want [IsEqualGUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which uses memcmp behind the scenes) or just use `operator==` (which calls IsEqualGUID for you).

Answer (score 2):

Is the == operator not overloaded to do this for you? Or use [IsEqualGUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680575%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Wine implementation in here: https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/ole32/compobj.c

Is fast simple and obvious:

```
    /***********************************************************************
 *           IsEqualGUID [OLE32.@]
 *
 * Compares two Unique Identifiers.
 *
 * PARAMS
 *  rguid1 [I] The first GUID to compare.
 *  rguid2 [I] The other GUID to compare.
 *
 * RETURNS
 *  TRUE if equal
 */
#undef IsEqualGUID 
BOOL WINAPI IsEqualGUID(
    REFGUID rguid1, REFGUID rguid2)  {
  return !memcmp(rguid1, rguid2, sizeof(GUID));
}
```

That will compile with any Visual Studio version out there. That also is C so C++ aficionado might wrap it up in `extern "C" {  }`

Comment: The OP is asking specifically for a solution that compiles with Visual Studio 2010. `constexpr` was introduced in C++11. Visual Studio 2010 does not support C++11.